# Calculating the density of known groups of points

Tags: python, cluster-computing, density-plot

I'm currently working on a project where the interplay between AD algorithms and visualizations is analysed. I've read a great amount of literature, and concluded that to fit my needs I would like to combine several metrics. I was able to realize most of them, yet, this one is missing:

Say I have a 2D space occupied by points belonging to one of 2 classes. I would like to calculate the density of each group. The labels of the groups are known. When looking around stackoverflow etc. I read about DBSCAN alot, but to my understanding DBSCAN is used to perform clustering itself. I already have the clusters, and would like to know their density.

I would appreciate any suggestions or guidance toward a known metric. 
If existant, please also share the needed python labraries with me.

Thank you very much.

This is what my data can look like:

```
array([[-3.90611544e+00, -5.47953465e-01],
       [-5.22999684e+00,  5.56145331e-01],
       [-4.84611012e+00,  5.54304197e-02],
       [-4.85019718e+00, -3.19791419e-01],
       [-4.59453620e+00,  5.70821744e-01],
       [-6.65068624e+00, -9.97229190e-01],
       [-6.57787930e+00, -5.03538827e-01],
       [-4.80275333e+00, -8.42197968e-02],
       [-4.55720113e+00,  8.23122108e-01],
       [-4.47469205e+00, -6.77669238e-01],
       [-5.84095559e+00, -8.19564981e-01],
       [-4.93963103e+00, -8.66167854e-01],
       [-4.98336307e+00, -4.45923700e-02],
       [-4.56953722e+00, -4.27976712e-01],
       [-6.25553298e+00,  1.32863878e-01],
       [-6.11860914e+00, -1.09009817e+00],
       [-5.60347264e+00,  1.34600670e+00],
       [-4.85974421e+00, -2.03600566e-01],
       [-4.38049846e+00,  1.27302889e+00],
       .......
```

which plots like this: 
[cannot include pictures yet, see link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDX2F.png)

I would now like to get a density value for the red and green clusters each.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Corrected my code. Also please note that this algorithm is of complexity O(n^2): For 10240 points it takes almost 1 minute to run on a fast machine.

UPDATE 2: Return the inverse: count/total_distance

UPDATE 3:
If, as you mentioned above, density visualization is a goal, I think that the sample plot you provided is, in itself, a good visual representation of density to the observer.

UPDATE 4: Based on the below comment, I eliminated double-counting and the algorithm is now of complexoty O(n^2/2) and, naturally, runs twice as fast.

A marginal improvement, especially in the case of several clusters, would be to paint the points in each clusted with a hue of a single color that varies based on the cluster's average density, say, light blue to dark blue.

As [DerekG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9831777/derekg) pointed out, you could use other density measures for the above scheme.

Another idea would be to compute each point's LOCAL density by counying the number of its neighbors and, if the number of neighbors exceeds a certain threshold, then to visually highlight the point by coloring it with a contrasting color, say black.

Please note that the code sample I provided in this answer can easily be modified to implement any of the above mentioned approaches including those by [DerekG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9831777/derekg)

I'm not an expert at cluster analysis but I'll try to help:

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

The answer depends on the definition of density. If you define density as the average distance of all pairs of points in the cluster, then this code is the answer:

```
from  math import sqrt
points = [
    [1, 3],
    [2, 4],
    [9, 1],
    [2, 6],
    [5, 3],
]
def density(points):
    total_distance = 0
    count = 0
    i = 0
    for x1,y1 in points:
        for x2,y2 in points[i+1:]:
            count += 1
            total_distance += sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)
        i += 1
    print(count)
    return count/total_distance

print(density(points))
```

Which prints:

```
0.2131384729384717
```

Comment: As noted here there are many definitions for density and each will get you different results. Average distance between pairs is one. Using a set window and counting the total number of each class per that window's area is another. A third is to treat the points as a normal distribution and use the variance of the distribution as a density metric. Any might give you desirable properties based on your use case

Comment: Thanks for the idea! One more question about your code: By looping over the array twice, don't you get duplicate distances for each distance? E.g. first iteration in first loop gives you [1,3] for x1,y1 and second iteration in the second loop gives you x2,y2 = [2,4]. Now, Second iteration in the first loop gives you x1,y1 =[2,4] and the first iteration in the second loop gives x2,y2 =[1,3], which is a distance we already addedd to the total distance, right? Doesn't that increase the distance with duplicate information?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this issue which, however, only affects the efficiency of the algorithm not the accuracy of the result because, even though the distance is doubled the count is also doubled. I've updated the code to fix the efficiency problem.